# Simplest way to check if current user has permission to a MySQL table (from PHP / mysqli) for some desired operation?

Tags: mysql, permissions, php, mysqli

While using an already established mysqli connection to a MySQL database from PHP, I'm looking for a simple way to check if this connection (i.e. the authenticated user for this connection, if any) has some desired access to a certain table (or at least any access to the table whatsoever).

If it matters, the table in question is in another database than the currently `USED` one, and I'm trying to access it by the following kind of query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_other_database_on_the_same_server_as_the_currently_used_database.some_table WHERE id = 1
```

My research so far has only found the ridiculously complex solution of manually parsing and resolving the depressingly messy raw-string output of the `SHOW GRANTS` command, which I just cannot accept being the only way of doing this!?

Things I have tried (and failed) so far are the following:

**1.**
To simply perform the desired operation in question against the table in question, and evaluate the error codes if it fails. To my big surprise, a `SELECT` query (issued e.g. with the `mysqli_query()` API) simply returns `False` if I don't have the appropriate permissions for the table in question, without any error code or error message being reported at all (inspected both manually in the debugger on the connection object and by means of the `mysqli_error()` API). The problem with this is that `False` will also be returned if e.g. the queried table doesn't exist at all, so I cannot know from this if it failed because of permission problems or because of something completely different.

**2.**
To search for some kind of equivalent of the `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` command [of Microsoft SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83474/verify-if-user-has-read-access-to-a-table), which I always come up empty-handed with though, consistently just being politely herded back by Google to the extremely clumsy `SHOW GRANTS` command of MySQL.

So my question is, again:

**How can I, with no holds (or hacks) barred, check if my mysqli connection has some desired access (or at least read access if nothing else) to a certain MySQL table?**

There really ***must*** be some easy way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this can lead to some `SELECTs` to solve your problem?

For the 'ana_index':

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR ana_index@localhost;
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ana_index'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...'
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'ana_index'@'localhost'
```

These tables were populated:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'ana_index'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
              Host: localhost
              User: ana_index
          Password: *1E62D0DB2482ED4455102B56D823285C02BAAF8F
       Select_priv: N
       Insert_priv: N
       Update_priv: N
       Delete_priv: N
       Create_priv: N
(etc)

mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE user = 'ana_index'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Host: localhost
               Db: test
             User: ana_index
      Select_priv: Y
      Insert_priv: Y
      Update_priv: Y
      Delete_priv: Y
      Create_priv: Y
        Drop_priv: Y
       Grant_priv: N
(etc)
```

`mysql.user` says what permissions, if any, the user has for all databases.

`mysql.db` says what permissions the user has for particular database(s), `test` in this example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you know of any similar technique for extracting permissions on the table level though (which the question was about more specifically)?

Comment: `mysql.table`...

Comment: After experimenting some with this, it seems like only the root user can access these tables you mention (or at least not my normal user anyway), which in that case seemingly counteracts the entire purpose of the question (i.e. asking for a method to check if my current mysqli connection has some desired access, or at least read access if nothing else, to a certain MySQL table). Or am I missing something? More specifically, the call `mysqli_query($db_conn_handle, 'SELECT * FROM mysql.tables_priv')` only returns `false` when I attempt it from my PHP program (same happens for `mysql.db` etc)?

Comment: `mysqli_query` does not return a resultset, it returns a handle with which you can fetch the rows in various ways.  The [_docs_](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli) might be a quick way to see what to do, then study the PHP docs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite aware of how `mysqli_query` works, including that when it returns `false` (instead of such a handle) the query _failed_ (contrary to just not returning any result). This, ironically enough, brings us back to the exact dilemma behind my question to begin with - how can I know if such a failure is due to a permission problem or something else (e.g. the table not existing to begin with)? Since the same query succeeds under the root user though, I can only assume that a low-privilege user is not permitted to access the tables you mention, in turn invalidating this as a solution?

Comment: After every `mysqli_query` call, check for errors, not just by listening for `false`, but also by calling `mysqli_error` and/or `mysqli_errno` to see what the errors is.

Comment: Yes, thanks again, but unfortunately no error code or error string is returned at all from `mysqli_error()` / `mysqli_errno()` after the query fails, which is actually **also** part of the exact problem that this entire question is about. Quoted from my question above: _"...simply returns `false` if I don't have the appropriate permissions for the table in question, without any error code or error message being reported at all (inspected both manually in the debugger on the connection object and by means of the `mysqli_error()` API)"_ ...which brings us back to the original question. :-(

Comment: (Sorry, I did not read carefully enough.)  I wonder if no-permissions comes back as no-error-message, yet other errors come back with useful info in `mysqli_error`?  I get lots of errors in my own code, and there has always been something in mysqli_error().  (I have not tested the no-permissions case.)

Comment: As _**again**_ (come on now... ;-)) mentioned in my original question above, unfortunately at least the case where the table in question does not exist also fails without any error message/code whatsoever, so the method of "assuming a permission error if the query fails without any error message/code" sadly does not work either. :-(